# Como integrar e fazer queries com pymongo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Estou aprendendo a integrar Python e MongoDB e, por conta disso, me propus um desafio: criar um pequeno programa para cadastrar jogadores de futebol.

Meu programa tem dois módulos, info_player e info_team. Minha intenção é rodar o programa interativamente(python -i). O primeiro módulo recebe informações sobre os jogadores e o segundo, informações sobre o time, além de conversar com o banco.

Estruturei o banco da seguinte forma, database é chamada campeonato, as collections são os times e os documents são os jogadores. Ou seja, há um relacionamento one-to-many entre times e jogadores.

Minhas dúvidas são: preciso converter os objetos gerados para Json(pensei em criar um método `to_json`)? Como salvar no banco e fazer as queries desejadas?

info_player:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, nationality="brazilian", team):
        """
        initializating Jogador class
        """
        self.personal(name, age, country)
        self.professional(team)

    def personal(self, name, age, nationality, dominancy, height):
        """
        personal data about players
        """
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.nationality = nationality
        self.height = height
        self.dominancy = dominancy  # righty, lefty or ambidextrous

    def profissional(self, position, number, team, primary):
        """ 
        professional data about players
        """
        self.position = position
        self.number = number
        self.team = team
        self.primary = False  # is he a regular member of a team?

    def to_Json():
```

info_team:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from info_player import Player


class TeamDB:
    def __init___(self, nome, fundacao, federacao):
        self.name = name
        self.foundationData = foundationData
        self.federation = federation

    def initializeDB():
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        global base
        base = client.league

    def toMongo():
        """
        receive a player object and save it 
        """
    def playersByPosition():
        """
        query players by position
        """
    def lineup():
        """
        receive a team and return its starting line-up, players with primary = true
        """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo à tua primeira pergunta: não, não precisas de converter para JSON. O modulo pymongo fornece a possibilidade de aceder às *collections* e fazer queries de Mongo (Ex.: db.nome_da_collection.find({})).

Sugiro que o processo de aceder à database seja desta maneira:

```
import pymongo

DB_URL = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/<nome da bd>'

COLLECTION_NAME = '<nome da collection>'

src_db = pymongo.MongoClient(DB_URL).get_database() #src_db agora vai ter acesso à base de dados

collection = src_db.get_collection(COLLECTION_NAME) #collection vai ter agora acesso à collection desejada
```

A partir de agora basta fazeres as queries tal como fazes no Mongo. Por exemplo, se quiseres percorrer todos os documentos da collection Teams:

```
for team in src_db.collection.find({}):
    ...
```

Pela mesma ordem de ideias, se quiseres encontrar um jogador com um certo id (?) podes fazer:

```
player = src.collection.find_one({'id':12345})
```

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer duvida dispõe.